# How to convert userscript to Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, userscripts

I'm trying to convert usescript to Firefox addon but it's not working (It works with all modern browsers except Firefox). I tried https://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.php it converts userscript and its working but add-on fails at validation and I can't submit it at Firefox add-on catalog.

Here is my code http://pastebin.com/mxnBqDxS

Is there easy way to create Firefox add-on whit this script that won't fail at validation?

Comment: Hi Wladimir thanks for reply.

Here is validation results:
http://pastebin.com/h8MAvHXq

Comment: All these seem to be warnings, not errors. Do they actually make the validation fail or can you ignore them and proceed? If it is the former - which particular warning is being considered critical?

Comment: I can submit my add-on but it gets rejected by AMO editors after 2-3 days. Here is e-mail I got from them: http://pastebin.com/jQSGa4Jy 

Problem is I don't know how to fix the mentioned problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment the extension wasn't rejected by the automatic validation (that always produces many warnings that have no real implications) but rather by the human reviewer. The reviewer considered the following line in your script to be unsafe:

```
button.innerHTML = wrapper.text;
```

The reviewer is wrong however and you should reply to the mail (your reply will be sent to amo-editors mailing list) pointing out that:

1. `wrapper.text` isn't some text that is provided by the web page or the user. It is rather something that is hardcoded in your extension, its possible values are known in advance and sanitization is unnecessary.
2. Even *if* `wrapper.text` were some text that you got from the web page - `button` is being inserted as an element of that very web page. This means that any JavaScript code that executes because of improper sanitization executes with the privileges of the web page. The web page doesn't get any more privileges than it already has.

So while `innerHTML` is a common source of security issues, in this case it isn't.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir, I e-mailed AMO editors and my add-on is preliminarily reviewed and it's on Firefox add-ons catalog.